# Descriptors in key-features during mapping

Tags: computer-vision, features

This question is related to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51373/what-is-the-difference-between-features-and-descriptors-in-computer-vision).

In SLAM-type applications the feature detectors like SIFT are used for finding keypoints in the images to be matched. The candidate keypoints are matched by aligning warped patches around these points (as far as I can understand). 
What is the role of the descriptor vector in this process. Is it used for selecting the best candidate in the neighborhood?